# Is there any way to format time like below using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
let time = 'Thu Aug 05 2021 13:56:21 GMT+0530'
let formattedTime = moment(time).format('hh mm');
```

> This `formattedTime` will return 01 30 for this value. Can I get 01h 30M using moment() ?

Comment: yes, https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Thanks, @sid, and Bravo. `moment(time).format('hh[h] mm[m]')` This also works for me.

Comment: it's good that the documentation helped

Answer (score 1):

May be you can't like 01h 30M but you can do with custom code

```
let time = 'Thu Aug 05 2021 13:56:21 GMT+0530'
let hour = moment(time).format('hh') + 'h' ;
let minute = moment(time).format('mm') + 'M' ;

const formatedTime = `${hour} + ${minute}`

console.log(formatedTime)
```